# Server side (or clientside??) solution to prevent multiple ajax requests across sessions?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js, twitter, server-side

I had a quick question. I have a login on my site (using Auth0 + Firebase). The site is using Ember JS. When you login, you have a dashboard, and when you click on the "Display" button, it shows a live feed pulling from Twitter's API and Instagram's API using AJAX requests. However, if you open the same page on multiple screens with the same user, it makes double the ajax requests, or triple depending on the amount of screens it's on. Is there any way to make this server side? Have it make the requests once on the server and then just fetch it from there live?

Ideally, I would like for people to login across multiple computers, click their "display button", and be projected the same stream. I figure this would need to be server side, i'm just at a loss of where to even start. I essentially just want to prevent 15 simultaneous ajax requests across sessions, and just have them fetch the 1. Is this even possible?

Thanks for the help is advance!

Comment: You could use redis or your database to cache the twitter and Instagram data.

Comment: Right - so if I'm using firebase as my BaaS, let's say this happens:

- User opens a tab and starts the stream.
- All of the streams info is sent to Firebase & stored.
- User opens same stream on different computer (both authenticated into the same login)

At this step, how do I recognize that the user already opened a stream and stop the new window from starting the stream, but rather pulling from firebase?

Comment: I don't know firebase. I think you should find some way to access the data based on userid: Check data by userid -> check some timestamp for last update -> if last update is recent -> get from datastore -> else initiate twitter/instagram feed (and start storing it by userid)

Comment: I like this idea, I didn't think about putting a timestamp on the data. Do you think there would be a bit more of an efficient method to do this? Possibly something server side? Like, what would happen if it's a slow day and the last update was like an hour ago?

I really appreciate the help on this.

Comment: I guess your ember app should always ask data from your own backend. And backend should decide where to get data from (database or 3rd party api). I think this is the best way of building apps.

Comment: That's what I meant, I presumed firebase is a backend...

Comment: Firebase is my backend. It's basically just a JSON structured database. I'm just thinking if a search is inactive for a while, the stream would get confused and falsely create 2 AJAX requests?

I'm just open to other ideas. I appreciate ya'lls inputs.

Comment: Any updates on this? Anyone have any other ideas?